# Ubuntu 18.04 On Screen Keyboard Customization

Tags: 18.04, onscreen-keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with a touchscreen device. 
The On Screen Keyboard (OSK) is working normally, except, there's no ctrl, alt buttons.

[image]

please help on

1. What is the name of the osk app? (whenever possible, I don't want to install any other app like onboard, florence, etc)
2. How do I customize the osk app ? I want to remove some keys (especially the one like flag, second from the right, last row). And also remove the transparency.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to save file with this keyboard. Nano - no CTRL, vim - no Esc to get out of insert mode. Useless OSK.

Comment: I have the same issue. I wanted to know if the OSK is working with google chrome ?.